# How can I quickly perform substitutions in integration?

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals, substitution

If i want to integrate
$$\int \sin x \cos x \, dx $$
and I let $u = \sin x$, then how do I work out what $dx$ is? I know that you can do
\begin{align}
\frac{du}{dx} &= \cos x \\[5pt]
\frac{dx}{du} &= \frac{1}{\cos x} \\[5pt]
dx &= \frac{du}{\cos x} \, ,
\end{align}
but is there a shorter way that I can get there? I am asking because sometimes when I watch Youtube videos on integration by substitution where they can do it directly. Are they doing it mentally?

Comment: This way requires three steps, why do you need a shorter way?

Comment: Formatting tip: your post will look better and be easier to read if you use `\sin x`, `\cos x` etc

Comment: ok @saulspatz  i will note that.

Comment: Yes, they're doing it mentally, and you will too, with a bit more practice.

Comment: If $\frac{du}{dx}=\cos x$, then $du=\cos x \, dx$. Since the term $\cos x \, dx$ already appears in the integrand, there is no need to make $dx$ the subject of the equation: just replace $\cos x \, dx$ with $du$. With practice, you can skip the $\frac{du}{dx}=\cos x$ step and simply write $du=\cos x \, dx$, meaning that you can perform the substitution mentally.

Comment: Maybe consider the anti derivative of $sin2x$?

Comment: ok @joe , got it.

Comment: @DiegoMath No need for a substitution as $f(x)f'(x)=\frac12(f(x)^2)$.

Comment: @sweetlovely: By the way, the theory that underpins integration by substitution is to do with the 'reverse chain rule':$$\int f'(g(x))g'(x) \, dx = f(g(x))+C \, .$$In this case, $f'(t)=t$ and $g(x)=\sin x$, so again making an actual substitution seems unnecessary.

Comment: @diegomath i dont understand what you're saying .you're probably doing higher level math than me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $\frac{du}{dx}=\cos x$, then $du=\cos x \, dx$. Since the term $\cos x \, dx$ already appears in the integrand, there is no need to make $dx$ the subject of the equation. With practice, you can skip the $\frac{du}{dx}=\cos x$ step and simply write $du=\cos x \, dx$, meaning that you can perform the substitution mentally.

In this particular case, there are two viable alternatives to this method: as imranfat mentions in the comments, you can use the identity $\sin 2x=2\sin x \cos x$. Then,
$$
\int\sin x \cos x \, dx = \int\frac{1}{2}\sin2x \, dx 
$$
At this stage, you *could* make the substitution $u=2x$, but that strikes me as a waste of time. Just note that
$$
\frac{d}{dx}\left(-\cos2x\right)=2\sin2x
$$
and so
$$
\frac{d}{dx}\left(-\color{#F01C2C}{\frac{1}{4}}\cos2x\right)=\color{#F01C2C}{\frac{1}{2}}\sin2x
$$
and you're finished. Again, with practice you can do this mentally.

The second method is to note that
$$
\frac{d}{dx}\left(\sin^2x\right)=2\sin x\cos x \, ,
$$
from which we get
$$
\int \sin x\cos x \, dx = \frac{\sin^2 x}{2}+C \, .
$$
Note that $\frac{\sin^2 x}{2}$ and $-\frac{1}{4}\cos2x$ simply differ by a constant, meaning that they are both antiderivatives of the function in question.